# Why is 'GET' verb used for my link on a rails web site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link constructed as follows:

```
<td><%= link_to "Delete", "/admins/delete_user?id=#{u.id}", :method=>"post",
        :confirm=>"Are you sure?", :remote=>:true, :class=>"alert" %>
```

Since I specify `post` for the method, I expect `POST`. `rake routes` produces the following:

```
admins_delete_user POST   /admins/delete_user(.:format)                                                            admins#delete_user
```

The following error occurs after I select the link.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admins/delete_user"):
```

Why does the controller use `GET`?

Comment: please post the output of `$ rails routes` to the question.

Comment: `Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET.` From [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). Do you have all the JavaScript loaded?

Comment: Why would you use POST request to delete something instead of the conventional DELETE requests?